# .asFormUrlEncoded() to retrieve data from hashMap<String, String>

Tags: java, playframework, hashmap, multipartform-data

I'm sending a video file along with some user details to my play framework application using MultipartRequest, the user details are added to a hashmap `Map<String, String> myMap;`on the server side I have retrieved my video file using .`asMultipartFormData();`

I was trying to retrieve my map using .`asFormUrlEncoded();` but that uses `Map<String, String[]>`

So I've only been able to retrieve one value from my hash map, if I try to retrieve anymore using this code

```
for(int i =0; i < myMap.size(); i++){
            String param = "param" + (i + 1);
            System.out.println(myMap.get(param)[i]);    
        }
```

I get an arrayOutOfBounds error, is there an alternative solution to retrieve the data from the MultipartFormData, or can I implement my loop differently?

maybe I shouldn't be using `.asFormUrlEncoded();`at all to retrieve the hashmap?

**EDIT**

I've modifed my code to use an iterator

```
Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = myMap.keySet().iterator();
        while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String[] value= myMap.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        }
```

This prints my key, but returns `Ljava.lang.String;@` for the values, I think this is because the `.asFormUrlEncoded();` is expecting a `<String, string[]>`, but my hashMap uses `<String, String>`  any solution to this?

Comment: I added the `playframework` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
    Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = myMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        String[] value= myMap.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value[0]);
    }
```